# How to test runtime arguments via mocha?

Tags: node.js, testing, command-line-arguments, mocha.js

I am using mocha to test some code that I'm writing in node.js.

One of my programs is designed to run from the command line with runtime arguments. As several of the options are directories, the code validates the options and determines if the directories exist, including an optional base directory.

This is something I would like to test with mocha, however the code isn't designed to be imported, as it's designed to run from the command line.

So my question is, how do I test command line arguments for a program via mocha?

I've tried googling, but alas I keep getting articles about mocha that mention mocha's command lines, not how to test command lines for node.js code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change your code to be test-friendly using the following steps:

- put command-line argument parsing and processing into a function that takes an array of strings as an argument and returns a parsed configuration object. In your test, you can synthesize the command line arguments to exercise your code. In production, you just send in `process.argv`.
- put the directory validation stuff in separate functions that can easily be tested using the normal mocha mechanisms, using files created under `/tmp` for any filesystem I/O you want to really perform.

That should get you pretty far, but if you still want to test what your program does with stdout, stderr, etc, use the `child_process` node core module to run your program and then you can make assertions in your mocha tests about the exit code, content written to stdio, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do the first point as I'm using the opt lib.

My problem was that I'm not exporting any 'function' in the code, as the code isn't designed as a model, it's designed as the executing program. But then I presume I cannot get around that if I wish to use it in mocha.

Comment: You'll get better answers with a code snippet. Generic answers are tough.

Comment: There's no point posting code re the opt lib, I'm not that happy with it and was considering changing to something else. I think my main concern was around how I'm using the js file as the 'executable' and thus was not exposing any component in it as usable if the .js was 'required' by another piece of code. I presume I have no way around that though, if I wish to use it in mocha.